# javax.ws.rs.Produces equivalent in Spring

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, restful-architecture

Is there an equivalent annotation for `@Produces(javax.ws.rs.core.  MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)` in the package `org.springframework.web.bind.annotation` in order not to mix both ? as I am doing now...

```
@PostMapping("/price-menu")
    @Produces(javax.ws.rs.core. MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public ResponseEntity<Currency> menus 
            (HttpServletRequest request) {
..
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@PostMapping has a parameter named `produces`. (https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/PostMapping.html#produces--)

You can use it like this: `@PostMapping(path = "/price-menu", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")`